# Play/Pause and Elapsed Time not updating in iOS command center properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mpmediaitem, mpnowplayinginfocenter

I have a video player that can play from the iOS command center and lock screen. When I toggle a play/pause button in my app, it should update the play/pause button in the command center (`MPRemoteCommandCenter`) by updating the `nowPlayingInfo` (`MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`). I'm not sure why it's not updating.

For example, if I pause the video with a custom button in my app, the command center still shows the pause button (meaning the video is still playing which is wrong.)

[image]

This is how I update the `nowPlayingInfo`:

```
func updateMPNowPlayingInforCenterMetadata() {
    guard video != nil else {
        nowPlayingInfoCenter.nowPlayingInfo = nil
        return
    }

    var nowPlayingInfo = nowPlayingInfoCenter.nowPlayingInfo ?? [String: Any]()

    let image: UIImage
    if let placeholderLocalURL = video.placeholderLocalURL, let placeholderImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: placeholderLocalURL.path) {
        image = placeholderImage
    } else {
        image = UIImage()
    }

    let artwork = MPMediaItemArtwork(boundsSize: image.size, requestHandler: { _ -> UIImage in
        return image
    })

    nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] = video.title
    nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle] = video.creator?.name ?? " "
    nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork] = artwork

    nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration] = Float(video.duration)
    nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = Float(currentTime) // CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentItem!.currentTime())
    nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate] = player.rate
    nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyDefaultPlaybackRate] = player.rate

    nowPlayingInfoCenter.nowPlayingInfo = nowPlayingInfo

    if player.rate == 0.0 {
        state = .paused
    } else {
        state = .playing
    }
}
```

With KVO, when the player's `rate` changes, I call this function:

```
// MARK: - Key-Value Observing Method

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    guard context == &assetPlaybackManagerKVOContext else {
        super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
        return
    }

    } else if keyPath == #keyPath(AVPlayer.rate) {
        updateMPNowPlayingInforCenterMetadata()
    }
}
```

Any thoughts?

### UPDATE

I found a solution though but not perfect in my case. So in my app I have 2 view controller's. Let's call them `FeedVC` and `PlayerVC`. So `FeedVC` has `AVPlayer`'s that are always playing but are muted. If you click on one of them, then the `PlayerVC` is created and plays the full video. **If I pause the `AVPlayer`'s in `FeedVC` before going to `PlayerVC` then the "play/pause" button in the NowPlayingInfoCenter works perfectly!**

Is there a way to make this work without having to pause the videos in the `FeedVC`?

**Another issue is that the `elapsed time` keeps counting if I don't pause the players in the `FeedVC`. It seems that if multiple players are playing, the play/pause button and elapsed time are incorrect.**

Comment: I got you man just give me time to get home and I'll show you my solution.

Comment: iam also facing same problem..did you found solution for this

Answer (score 12):

When you setting the dictionary for `nowPlayingInfo` you will want to set the `MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate` value appropriately. The `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` is expecting either a `1.0` (playing) or `0.0` (not playing) value as a `Double` wrapped in a `NSNumber` object. Below you will find the code for how I'm setting the `nowPlayingInfo` in my project.

```
func setNowPlayingMediaWith(song: SUSong, currentTime: Double?) {

    var playingInfo:[String: Any] = [:]

    if let title = song.title {
        playingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] = title
    }

    if let songID = song.id {
        playingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID] = songID
    }
    if let artist = song.artist, let artistName = artist.name {
        playingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyArtist] = artistName
    }

    if let album = song.album, let albumTitle = album.title {
        var artwork:MPMediaItemArtwork? = nil
        if let album = song.album, let artworkData = album.artwork {
            artwork = MPMediaItemArtwork(boundsSize: Constants.Library.Albums.thumbSize, requestHandler: { (size) -> UIImage in
                return UIImage(data: artworkData as Data)!
            })
        }
        if artwork != nil {
            playingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork] = artwork!
        }
        playingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle] = albumTitle
    }

    var rate:Double = 0.0
    if let time = currentTime {
        playingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = time
        playingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration] = song.duration
        rate = 1.0
    }
    playingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate] = NSNumber(value: rate)
    playingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyMediaType] = NSNumber(value: MPNowPlayingInfoMediaType.audio.rawValue)
    MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = playingInfo
}
```

In this method I am passing the `song` that my player is has currently loaded. Whenever the user chooses to play or pause I call `setNowPlayingMediaWith(song:currentTime:)` to update the device's control console.

I keep track of the `currentTime` (`Double`) as a property of my player. If there is a `currentTime` passed in that means we are meant to be playing, so set the `MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate` to `1.0` and set the `MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime` to `currentTime`. This will set the current time to start automatically playing in the device's control console.

Likewise, if there is no `currentTime` passed then we have stopped or paused. In this case we set the `MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate` to `0.0` and we do not include the `MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime`.

[Download](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sublam/id1212164011?ls=1&mt=8) my app to see this in action.

---

**EDIT** (answer to comments)

**"Is there a way to make this work without having to pause the videos in the FeedVC"**

Without seeing your code it is difficult to give you a definite answer. It would make sense though to pause any ongoing media before starting your `PlayerVC`'s media.

---

**"the elapsed time keeps counting"**

The elapsed time will countdown the elapsed time based on an `NSTimer` property on `NowPlayingInfoCenter`. This timer will stop only when the timers value has reached the value you set in `MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration`, or when you update the `MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime`.

My suggestion is to write a method that "clears out" the `NowPlayingInfoCenter`. This method should set the will set all of key values to either 0.0 or nil respectively. Call this "clear out" method each time before you play your media in `PlayerVC`. Then once you play from `PlayerVC`, set the `NowPlayingInfoCenter` key values like you would in the method I pasted in my answer to set the new values for the new playing media.

Comment: Doesn't my code automatically do this with `nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate] = player.rate` and `nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyDefaultPlaybackRate] = player.rate`?

Comment: Also, I got that from Apple's sample code: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/MPRemoteCommandSample/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017322

Comment: I will update my answer later tonight. I'm at work and don't have my personal computer on me. But I have done this in a personal project and it works great. I thought it went like the above but I will update this tonight.

Comment: Ok sure, thank you! Please also take a look at my "Update" because I also mention that `elapsed time` seems to not work properly.

Comment: @JEL I updated my answer. Please let me know if this helps you out. If not we can get on a chat and I can walk you through it.

Comment: I get the current time of the player with `CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentTime())`, but this does not return `nil`. Therefore with your function, when do you decide to pass in `nil` or not to the parameter `currentTime: Double?` ? Basically, with ``CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentTime())`` that means I never pass in `nil`

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I tried setting the `currentTime` to `nil` when I pause the video just for testing, but the play/pause button doesn't change correctly. I still think it's due to the other `AVPlayer`'s playing in a different view controller

Comment: Keep in mind it isn't a 100% copy and paste kind of thing. This is just what I've done in my project. You won't have an `SUSong` for example. Can you paste your code so I can see what you are doing?

Comment: Yep I get that its not copy/paste : ) Quick question, did you run a test where an AVPlayer is always playing in a different view controller -- similar to what I said in the `Update` of my question?

Comment: Did you see my previous comment and question above? ^^

Comment: @JEL The same issue is happening to me with an instance of AVPlayer and an instance of AVPlayerViewController. Luckily, there's an option on AVPlayerViewController to set updatesNowPlayingInfoCenter to false