# AVAudioEngine and AVAudioPlayerNode: Play/Pause not updating in iOS command center properly

Tags: ios, avaudioengine, remote-control

I have read [Play/Pause and Elapsed Time not updating in iOS command center properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43282423/play-pause-and-elapsed-time-not-updating-in-ios-command-center-properly)

I have tried `MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime`, `MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyDefaultPlaybackRate` and `MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate` .

I have updated the [apple demo](https://github.com/BoxDengJZ/AudioJz/tree/master/Projects/4_remote_control)

The apple demo is OK to show Play/Pause updating in iOS command center, with `AVPlayer`

Here is using `AVAudioEngine` and `AVAudioPlayerNode`, `AVAudioPlayerNode` plays audio by  `scheduleBuffer`.

Here is the relevant  iOS command center code:

```
func show(mediaInfo time: TimeInterval){
        let artistName = "test"
        
        guard let duration = length else {
            return
        }
        var isPlaying: Double = 0
        
        var pInfo: [String: Any] = [MPMediaItemPropertyArtist : artistName,
                                    MPMediaItemPropertyTitle : artistName ]
        if let img = UIImage(systemName: "music.note.list"){
            let artwork = MPMediaItemArtwork(boundsSize: img.size, requestHandler: {  (_) -> UIImage in
                return img
            })
            pInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork] = artwork
            
        }
        
        if streamer.state == .playing{
            isPlaying = 1
            pInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = time
            pInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration] = duration
        }
        pInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID] = artistName
        pInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate] = NSNumber(floatLiteral: isPlaying)
        pInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyDefaultPlaybackRate] = NSNumber(floatLiteral: isPlaying)
        pInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyMediaType] = NSNumber(value: MPNowPlayingInfoMediaType.audio.rawValue)
        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = pInfo
    }
```

here is [the example code](https://github.com/BoxDengJZ/AudioJz/tree/master/UnderTheHood)

---

The corresponding audio session:

```
func setupAudioSession() {
        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {
            try session.setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, policy: .default, options: [.allowBluetoothA2DP,.defaultToSpeaker])
            try session.setActive(true)
        } catch {
            os_log("Failed to activate audio session: %@", log: ViewController.logger, type: .default, #function, #line, error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

also tried

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {
            try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, options: AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker)
            audioSession.requestRecordPermission({ (isGranted: Bool) in
                
            })
        } catch  {}
```

Comment: To show your metadata in the command center you need to have an active non-mixable audio session category and to also be currently producing audio. Can you show your audio session configuration?

Comment: updated.  You can try the github code ,if convenient https://github.com/BoxDengJZ/AudioJz/tree/master/UnderTheHood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try stop AVAudioEngine.
like this:

```
engine.stop()
```

Answer (score 1):

better to use `engine.pause()`

```
   public func pause(){

        // Check if the player node is playing
        guard playerNode.isPlaying else {
            return
        }
        
        // Pause the player node and the engine
        playerNode.pause()
        
        // Update the state
        state = .paused
        engine.pause()
    }
```